# Parent overflow hidden not working when child is moved right by animation

Tags: css, css-animations

i am trying to move child div from its position to right with css3 animation. I have set the parent div overflow to hidden. but when moving child to right overflow hidden is not working.
How do i hide child while it is moving outside of parent region..

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="content">1</div>
</div>

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mostwanted_cJ/zcn9G/3)
```

Comment: Do you have a static width and height to the parent div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the code in Chrome and adding the animation for webkit as well (which I at first didn't do), I was able to solve this problem quite easily.

By adding `position: relative;` to the css of the `.container` everything should work as expected.

The CSS should look like this then.

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

And the [fiddle can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/zcn9G/6/).